# Multiple versions of Spark but can't set to Spark 2

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working with our company's computing cluster. I know it has Spark 2 since I am able to call it from a Jupyter notebook using PySpark. However, I would like to begin exploring the use of Spark with Scala through a command line interface (CLI). My question is, how do I change to Spark 2?

When running:

```
spark-submit --version
```

I got a message saying

```
Multiple versions of Spark are installed but SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION is not set
Spark1 will be picked by default
```

So I ran:

```
export SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION = 2
```

Then ran:

```
spark-submit --version

SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION is set to 2, using Spark2
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.2
      /_/

Type --help for more information.
```

1) The first message implies there are multiple Spark versions, so I tried to switch from 1 to 2. It seems that after setting the `PATH` to version 2, I am still using 1, which suggests that the first message is saying that I either have multiple versions of Spark1 or need additional configurations to set Spark to version 2. Is this the correct interpretation or is there something else I can do/try?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that it depends on your environment.

[Cloudera](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/spark2/latest/topics/spark_running_apps.html) says that there is 2 different scripts:

- `spark-shell` and `spark2-shell`
- `spark-submit` and `spark2-submit`

While [Hortonworks](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.0/bk_spark-component-guide/content/spark-choose-version.html) says about the environment variable (as you tried to set).

So you might want to check documentation for your environment, if you are not using any of these.